# ionic 2 execution android failed

Tags: ionic2

C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\dev\Breakingnews\trunk\Tawary\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml: Error: Found item String/google_app_id more than one time

:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.285 secs

Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\dev\Breakingnews\trunk\Tawary\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml: Error: Found item String/google_app_id more than one time

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

  > C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\dev\Breakingnews\trunk\Tawary\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml: Error: Found item String/google_app_id more than one time
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Can you provide us strings.xml?

Comment: Are you using phonegap-plugin-push? check https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/679

Comment: sorry, wrong issue link https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1660

Answer (score 0):

Cause of error is under the path \your project root\platforms\android\res\values then check in strings.xml, there are two with same attribute. You need to fix this according to your plugins definition.